# How does my 4k@120Hz display work over a 5Gb/s USB 3.1 cable?

Tags: displayport, usb-c

I have a GP27U 4k@120Hz display. Aside from HDMI and DisplayPort, this display allows you to connect over USB-C while also functioning as a USB hub and providing 90W of power. I checked the cable that comes with the display, and it says "SuperSpeed USB 3.1", which suggests that it's a 5Gb/s cable; the [rtings.com](https://www.rtings.com/monitor/reviews/cooler-master/tempest-gp27u) page for the display says the same. But 4k@120Hz requires around 30-40Gb/s throughput. So how does this actually work? Even if the video signal is going over DP Alt Mode, doesn't that still require the cable to send data at around 40Gb/s?

Comment: The 5 Gbps bandwidth will support 4K video at only 24 frames per second. This is far from 120HZ (120 frames per second). See [example link](https://www.pcmag.com/news/slaying-the-cable-monster-what-you-need-to-know-about-hdmi-cables).

Comment: And yet it works at 4k@120Hz. In fairness, I don't know for sure that the cable is 5Gb/s, but it does say "SuperSpeed USB 3.1" on the side. Perhaps it's actually 10Gb/s.

Comment: USB 3.1 is also known as USB 3.1 Gen 2 (10Gbps). A matter of terminology, which has changed lately.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 Gbps bandwidth will support 4K video at only 24 frames per second.
The fact that your cable can do 120HZ (120 frames per second)
means that it's not USB 3.1 Gen 1 (5Gbps)

The name "*SuperSpeed* USB 3.1" can stand for Gen 1 (5Gbps)
or Gen 2 (10Gbps). Strictly speaking, Gen 2 should be called
"SuperSpeed+".

The USB notation has taken a rather confusing turn when USB 3.1 came out
in 2013. Here is an historical note from the article
[USB terminology can be confusing](https://myemail.constantcontact.com/USB-terminology-can-be-confusing--read-this-article-to-shed-some-light-.html?soid=1117056847591&aid=WGje5qWtUts):

> USB 3.1 hit the market in 2013 and already offered higher transfer
> speeds. Alongside this came the decision to change the name of the USB
> 3.0 standard to USB 3.0 Gen 1 and to giving the new SuperSpeed+ standard the catchy name USB 3.1 Gen 2. This is made even worse by the
> fact that USB 3.1 Gen 1 is mostly being referred to as USB 3.1 or even
> USB 3.0.
>
> Which connector you’re actually dealing with most of the times can
> only be found out by looking at the symbol next to the port as well as
> the color-coding of the connector. A USB 2.0 plug is black, USB 3.1
> Gen 1 is blue and USB 3.1 Gen 2 is red. Besides those there are also
> other colors like yellow for the so called “PowerUSB” USB 2.0 ports
> which can put out 1A of power instead of 0,5A.

Unfortunately, not all cable makers are really strict with their markings.

You may find more interesting bits of information in the linked article.

Comment: Actually, I discovered that a 5Gb/s cable can become a 20Gb/s DP cable if all 4 lanes are used in DP Alt Mode (with USB2 hub speeds), and a 10Gb/s DP cable if only 2 lanes are used in DP Alt Mode (with 5Gb/s USB3 hub speed from the remaining 2 lanes). Given my chroma subsampling and DSC settings, it's conceivable that the cable is in fact a Gen1x1 5Gb/s cable.

Comment: That's not it. DisplayPort bandwidth is simply entirely unrelated to the USB speed rating.

Comment: What determines the maximum DisplayPort bandwidth of a USB-C cable in 2-lane mode?

Comment: See this nice [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/gnyyyc/how_can_usbc_that_can_only_handle_10gbps_handle/). According to it, DisplayPort in alternate mode can deliver up to 32.4 Gbps maximum link bandwidth with each of the four USB-C lanes running at 8.1 Gbps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this display bandwidth calculator helps shine some light on things: https://linustechtips.com/topic/729232-guide-to-display-cables-adapters-v2/?section=calc&H=5120&V=2160&F=120&bpc=10&calculations=show&formulas=show

Using my cable, display 1 runs at 3840x2160@60Hz with USB3 hub speeds, while display 2 runs at 3840x2160@144Hz with USB2 hub speeds.

Display 1 is running in YCbCr4:2:2 mode. Using the calculator, this means that it requires 8.36Gb/s bandwidth. A 5Gb/s cable supports 10Gb/s DP Alt Mode bandwidth plus 5Gb/s USB3 data traffic, so that tracks.

Display 2 is running in 10-bit full RGB mode and appears to be using DSC. Using the calculator with 2x DSC compression selected, it seems this mode requires 19.59Gb/s, which just barely falls within 4-lane DP Alt Mode bandwidth of 20Gb/s. (And USB2 data is always supported even if the 4 lanes are saturated.)

So it's *plausible* that a 5Gb/s cable could support these modes of operation. (I've also tried connecting my cable to a portable SSD drive and had it show up as a 5Gb/s device, though that's hardly definitive.)